# Using VAMP Plugins with C#

Tags: c#, plugins

I am wondering how to use VAMP Plugins with C# for Visual Studio 2008? I have downloaded multiple VAMP Plugins already. Currently, I have tested them using Sonic Visualiser and it looks great! However, I am having some problems incorporating it to my C# program.

My problem is that whenever I try to reference the .dll file, it gives me an error, something about 'make sure you are referencing a valid assembly or COM object'. How do I get around this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean these: http://www.vamp-plugins.org/
As far as I can see, they are written in C++, so you can't add them as reference. You need to use P/Invoke to use those plugins.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks however!